# How To Call Postgres 11 Stored Procedure From Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I have a stored procedure in Postgres called `sales`, and it works well from `pgadmin`:

```
CALL sales();
```

However, when I call it from Python:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect (host ....)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc('sales')
conn.commit()
```

I get the following error message:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: sales() is a procedure
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM sales()
                 ^   
HINT:  To call a procedure, use CALL.
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your procedure is called sales, you just need to "call" it e.g. `CALL sales()`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-call.html

I see what you are getting at, the python documentation here is misleading

"Calling a PostgreSQL stored procedure in Python steps"
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/call-stored-procedures/

Essentially the callproc is currently outdated (written for postgres 10 and below) and still considers procedures to be a function. So unless they update this, you will need to execute your own SQL in this instance like so

`cur.execute("CALL sales();")`

or if the sales procedure required inputs:

`cur.execute("CALL sales(%s, %s);", (val1, val2))`

Comment: How it shall be call from python scripts ... cur.callproc

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully this is of some use now.

Comment: Thank you Lucas ! It works perfectly.  You bless my day !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to call PostgreSQL **Stored_Procedure** in Python Script :

```
import pyodbc  
import psycopg2  
import io  
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
from urllib.parse import quote  

#define your PostgreSQL connection here:  

    host="Provide Host Name"   
    dbname="Provide Database Name"    
    user="Provide User"   
    password="Provide Password"   
    engine=create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:5432/{}.format(user,quote(password),host,dbname))   
    conn=engine.raw_connection()   
    cur=conn.cursor()  

#This will be your code to call stored procedure:   

    cur.execute('''call storedProcedureName()''')  
    
    conn.commit() # This is mandatory because we want to commit changes to DB 
    cur.close()  
    conn.close()  
    time.sleep(60) # timeout (optional)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.