# Call Postgresql Proocedure using python

Tags: python, postgresql

Trying to run a postgresql procedure using python but not able to rectify the error..

```
def call_procedure_without_arguments():
    try:
        connection = create_connection()
        if connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            # Call the procedure without any input arguments
            procname = "call proc_test"
            cursor.callproc(procname)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            print("Results:", results)

            # Commit the changes (if any)
            connection.commit()

            # Close the cursor and connection
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

            print("Procedure executed successfully.")
        else:
            print("Connection failed. Unable to call the procedure.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: Unable to call the procedure.", e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_procedure_without_arguments()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The argument to `cursor.callproc()` should just be the procedure name, it shouldn't have `call` before it. So `procname = 'proc_test'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Call Postgres 11 Stored Procedure From Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999993/how-to-call-postgres-11-stored-procedure-from-python)

Comment: @Barmar, that is wrong `callproc()` can't be used with procedures only functions. See my answer for doc reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the name `callproc` is not for procedures. It is for functions only:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.callproc

> Note

> callproc() can only be used with PostgreSQL functions, not with the procedures introduced in PostgreSQL 11, which require the CALL statement to run. Please use a normal execute() to run them.

Therefore:

`cur.execute('call proc_test')`

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting that no arguments need to be passed. The documentation for this is different at different resources.

According to [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/execute-postgresql-stored-procedure-and-function-in-python/)

```
 engine = connector.cursor()
 engine.callproc('your_procedure')
 result = cursor.fetchall()
```

If does not work try adding **parenthesis ()**, according to [Postgresql Tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/call-stored-procedures/):

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
cur.execute("CALL your_procedure();")
conn.commit();
```